How to remove empty csv lines of csv files in batch
I'm using git bash, so I suppose it's ok to ask questions in Unix forum, but I'm not familiar with Unix, only use ls, find and grep, so pls correct me if I'm wrong.
I have hundreds of .csv files and each might have up to several hundred lines.
Now I would like to remove the empty csv lines -- by empty csv lines, I'm not referring to lines with only blank spaces, but lines of all commas (,,,).
For example, a csv file has content as
Header2,Header3,Header5,Header7
a,b,c,d
,,,
aa,bb,cc,dd
,,,
,,,
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd
,,,
,,,
,,,

, there are hundreds of lines in the file, I would like to update it to
Header2,Header3,Header5,Header7
a,b,c,d
aa,bb,cc,dd
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd

And there are hundreds of such files, notice not all the csv files are to be updated, currently I'm using vim editor's vimgrep RegExPattern folders command, which filter out target csv files by regex pattern scanning its content, e.g. /,Header5,/ to filter out only csv files with Header5; then I'll use cdo g/RegExPattern/d | update | edit # command which can run a regex substitution on each hit file, e.g. here I use cdo g/\v^,*$/d to delete rows with only commas.
However, Vim replaces and logs each row removal, as there could be hundreds of matches in one file and there are hundreds of .csv files, it's pretty slow.
Is there a way to achieve this task in Unix?

Not foolproof in that there could be files like:
a,b,c,d
"a field with 3 commas on next line
,,,
",bvalue,cvalue,dvalue
"","","",""

Where ,,, is a false positive and "","","","" a false negative.
But you could delete the lines that don't contain characters other than , with:
grep -vlrZ --include='*.csv' '[^,]' /dir/with/csvs |
  xargs -r0 sed -i '/[^,]/!d'

Where grep finds the files with a least one line not containing a character other than ,, xargs passes the result to sed and sed edits them inplace to remove the lines other than the ones containing a character other than ,.
Though grep, xargs, sed are Unix commands, here we use non-standard GNU extensions (-r, -Z, --include, i; -r -0 have just been added to the POSIX specification of xargs).

any idea to handle the ,,, case pls?

Let's assume all your .csv files are in the current directory. Let's further assume that your target 'empty' lines are always multiple commas with nothing in between. You can then use something like this to remove 'empty' lines from all those files:
sed -i '/^,\{1,\}$/d' *.csv


i) if we are assuming the files are in the current directory, why complicate things with find instead of just sed '...' *.csv? ii) note that this will remove actually empty lines as well since ^,*$ will match on empty lines.

You are @terdon thank you. I edited the answer

they are in different subfolders actually but I get that sed is the keyword to look up. thanks!
